# How to login to W&B by using ENTRYPOINT

Tags: dockerfile, wandb

I want to know how to use ENTRYPOINT in a Dockerfile to run a shell script that logs me in.

Answer (score 0):

There’s no need for a custom entry point. Simply set the `WANDB_API_KEY` environment variable in a kubernetes spec or via the `-e` flag passed to `docker run`